# Browser does not follow the page charset

Tags: html

I defined a webpage to use `iso-8859-1` like the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

But when I open the page in the browser, the browser is using UTF-8 to read the page. Why the browsers does not following the page charset?

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your apache config, you should look in the httpd.conf (or equivalent) for the following directive:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

According to apache docs, this will override the meta declaration that you set. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset

You could turn it off by replacing the directive with this:

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the setting in the HTML will override whatever set up in the server. Comment AddDefaultCharset fixed my problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The information that really matters is the real Content-Type HTTP header sent by the web server. You can inspect it with Firebug of a similar tool. `<meta>` tags should only matter if you save the file to disk and the HTTP header is lost.